# J2ME key event handling

Tags: java, java-me, event-handling

I have created a textfield that takes all characters from the user.. but i want to disable the space so that user cant enter space ...help??

```
pin = new TextField("Pin#","",4,TextField.PASSWORD);
```

Comment: I am really stuck with this problem.Plz help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a PIN number then maybe you should replace the `constraints` parameter with `TextField.NUMERIC | TextField.PASSWORD`.

Comment: the application which i'm developing the client wants the pin number to be any character but not space

Comment: If any other character is acceptable then try `TextField.EMAILADDR` or `TextField.URL`, they should not allow spaces to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `ItemStateListener` interface. Then call `this.setItemStateListener(this)` in the Form constructor.
Implement the `itemStateChanged` method so that if the Item is the one you are interested in then get its content and test it if it contains spaces.

Comment: I think u didn't get my question....Whenever the user press the Spacebar key while entering in textfield i want to display warning message... can u help me with using keyevents... thanx

Answer (score 0):

In my case I create a MIDlet and a Form which contains a TextField. And it works. I do not know why did you say that the solution I gave you did not work to you ! Here is a very simple example I give ( I created it and tested it ! ) :

```
package hello;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

public class HelloMIDlet extends MIDlet {

    public Display display;

    public HelloMIDlet() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    }

    public void startApp() {
        Form f = new F(display);
        display.setCurrent(f);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

}

package hello;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.AlertType;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Item;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemStateListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;

public class F extends Form implements ItemStateListener {
    private TextField pin = new TextField("PIN :","",4,TextField.PASSWORD);
    private Alert alert;
    private Display disp;
    public F(Display d)
    {
        super("");
        disp = d;
        this.setItemStateListener(this);
        this.append(pin);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(Item item) {
        if (item == pin)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<pin.getString().length(); i++)
            {
                if (String.valueOf(pin.getString().charAt(i)).equals(new String(" ")))
                    displayAlert();
            }
        }
    }
    private void displayAlert()
    {
        alert = new Alert("Info","No space please !",null, AlertType.ERROR);
        disp.setCurrent(alert, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java SDK doesnot take  this.setItemStateListener(this); line shows error... thanx for the help neways